# Jquery filtering elements, Speed problem when elements increase

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I have produced a table but I am using `<div>`s instead of `<tr>`s and `<td>`s. here is an example:

```
<div class="tbl tbl1">
    <div class="thead">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td colTitle" style="width: 120px"><span>Title</span></div>
            <div class="td colLink" style="width: 190px"><span>Link</span></div>
            <div class="td colSize numeric" style="width: 75px"><span>Size(MB)</span></div>
            <div class="td colUploadDate" style="width: 75px"><span>UploadDate</span></div>
            <div class="td colOpen" style="width: 50px; max-width: 50px;"><span>Show</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td colTitle">
                <input type="text" class="Filter" />
            </div>
            <div class="td colLink">
                <input type="text" class="Filter" />
            </div>
            <div class="td colSize">
                <input type="text" class="Filter" />
            </div>
            <div class="td colUploadDate">
                <input type="text" class="Filter" />
            </div>
            <div class="td colOpen">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tbody">
    </div>
</div>
```

I will fill `tbody` part with server-side operations.

I use below codes to filter my rows based on values entered in filter inputs.

```
$(".Filter").on('input', function () {
      filterGrid();
      $(".rowCount").val($(".tbody .tr:visible").length);
});
function filterGrid() {
    $('.tbody .tr').each(function () {
        var v = 1;
        var x = $(this);
        $(".thead .Filter[value!='']").each(function () {
            var i = $(this).parent(".td").index();
            if (x.children(".td:eq(" + i + ")").html().indexOf($(this).val()) != -1) {
                v = v * 1;
            } else {
                v = 0;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (v == 1) {
            x.show();
        } else {
            x.hide();
        }
    });
}
```

My code works fine when I have a few number of rows, but when the number of loaded rows increases it takes more time to do filtering operation. Now I have two Question:

1- can my filter function be optimized to operate more rapidly?

2- when I enter the first letter I can't enter the second letter until the end of filtering based on the first letter. can I enforce javascript to break the operation and start a new one when I hit a button?

Comment: 1) yes. Move all the data into JavaScript days structures, do the filtering there and then synchronize to make the DOM reflect the result using jQuery.

Comment: 2) yes, but if you use (1) above it probably won't be required.

Comment: @mzedeler can you provide codes, please?